# arnova 10d G3 cant get past restore screen android

Tags: recovery-mode

I have a tablet by Arnova  and its not getting past the system recovery page after putting it into that mode by pressing vol+ and power button i see the green android sign for a bit and then goes to a dark screen and that's it .....any ideas please? its a 10d G3 by the way.